# Font size in dp (with libgdx FreeTypeFontGenerator)

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx, truetype

I'm adding some texts in my app using next code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal("fonts/myfont.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 28;
font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

And in the render:

```
font.draw(batch, "This is a super mega cool string label",
            0.15f * imageProvider.getScreenWidth(),
            0.95f * imageProvider.getScreenHeight());
```

But obviously this looks different in every device I run my app as the resolutions are not the same.

How can I use dp or something for having the same look & feel in all the devices?

Thanks!

----- UPDATE -----
I've tried to use:

```
int fontSize = (int)(28 * Gdx.graphics.getDensity());
```

And the text fits in a nexus4 but not in a S3Mini

Comment: S3Mini has display resolution of 320x533 DPs and Nexus 4 has resolution 384x640 DPs. I think that's why there is a problem with not fitting text.